# Python3.2 PyQt4 installation: UnboundLocalError

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, python-3.2

Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu to version 11.10 so I had to reinstall python3 modules. I downloaded latest PyQt4 but when I run configure.py I get following error:

```
    Qt Designer plugin disabled because Python library couldn't be found
An internal error occured.  Please report all the output from the program,
including the following traceback, to support@riverbankcomputing.com.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 2269, in <module>
    main()
  File "configure.py", line 2254, in main
    subdirs=pyqt.qpy_libs() + pyqt_modules + xtra_modules + pyqt.tools(),
  File "configure.py", line 957, in tools
    link = "%s -lpython%d.%d%s" % (lib_dir_flag, py_major, py_minor, abi)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lib_dir_flag' referenced before assignment
```

I really haven't got a clue what is wrong. btw. Before I upgraded Ubuntu to 11.10 I used python3.1 and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct `sip` packages installed before you try to build PyQt4. For ubuntu, I think you will need the `python-sip-dev` and `python3-sip-dev` packages (plus any dependencies). Alternatively, you could download and build the [latest version of sip](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) from source.

When you run the `configure.py` script for either pyqt or sip, it is essential that you use the correct version of python, e.g:

```
/usr/bin/python3.2 configure.py
```